# Приложение, полностью копирующее функционал сайта

Tags: objective-c

Здравствуйте. Недавно изучаю язык, подскажите в какую сторону копать, что лучше почитать, какие средства применить.
Суть вопроса: есть сайт, на нем есть авторизация (не через соц сети) и несколько разделов с объявлениями. Нужно создать приложение, полностью копирующее функционал сайта. т.е. просмотр объявлений, а после авторизации возможность подачи новых объявлений. Ну и изменения должны отображаться как в приложении, так и на сайте.
Надеюсь не сильно запутанно объяснил, заранее спасибо.

Comment: вам принципиально именно писать нативные приложения для ios?

Comment: Может легче сайт адаптировать под айфон?

Answer (score 1):

Гы, [фонгап](http://phonegap.com/) Вам нужен, юноша, чтобы силу поиметь ресурсами малыми. ©Йода

Comment: Человеческого мануала, как прикрутить рабочий сайт посредством PhoneGap на iphone не нашел.

Comment: Ну врядли будут мануалы такого рода: "Как захватить мир и продать за дорого, без убийств и смертей животных, для чайников по шагово в 32134 шагов".
Конечно Вам придется раскурить PhoneGap, чтобы понять как прикрутить рабочий сайт. А так чем Safari не подходит?

Comment: Да.. покурить придется не мало. Сафари всем устраивает, но есть такая вот задачка.